# Strip large pandas dataframe of whitespace

Tags: mysql, excel, pandas

I have what I am hoping is an easy thing ;)
I load a large dataset into a pandas dataframe from an excel file.
I then load that excel file into a mySQL table which has basically the same structure.

I have found that many of the cells in excel, have lots of trailing whitespace, which translates to whitespace in the columns in the table.

I am hoping there is a simple way to remove this whitespace before/while it is written to the database without massive loops. (i know there is the 'strip' method, but i think I'd have to loop through all the fields / rows.

Is there some simple switch that can be called during the read_excel or the to_sql, which would remove whitespace automatically? (likely daydreaming..)

I can also clean it up after it is loaded into the db - but i'm looking for any options before that.
Thanks!

Comment: do you know if rstrip (or strip) will load a cell that is only white space, as a null into the db? or will it be an empty string..

Comment: thanks yeah.. it sounds like my best option is to just do it once its in the db, as I'd like nulls instead of empty strings, and the operations seem like they would perform best in the db